# Pycharm doesn't install the library Pillow

Tags: python, pycharm

I was trying to install the package Pillow in the IDE Pycharm for my proyect, but when I try it, the console shows me this traceback.

```
writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'azure-pipelines.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching '.azure-pipelines'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.travis'
    writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    running build_ext


    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\DARWIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\setup.py", line 852, in <module>
        setup(
      File "C:\Users\Darwin Lozada\PycharmProjects\LearningPython\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      File "C:\Users\Darwin Lozada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\Darwin Lozada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\Darwin Lozada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Darwin Lozada\PycharmProjects\LearningPython\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
      File "C:\Users\Darwin Lozada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Users\Darwin Lozada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\Darwin Lozada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Darwin Lozada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Users\Darwin Lozada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\Darwin Lozada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Darwin Lozada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Users\DARWIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\setup.py", line 687, in build_extensions
        raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\DARWIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\setup.py", line 907, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html



    ----------------------------------------

Command ""C:\Users\Darwin Lozada\PycharmProjects\LearningPython\venv\Scripts\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\DARWIN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\Pillow\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record "C:\Users\Darwin Lozada\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-nfkxoa_3\install-record.txt" --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers "C:\Users\Darwin Lozada\PycharmProjects\LearningPython\venv\include\site\python3.8\Pillow"" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\DARWIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\
```

I don't know what can be the problem.

I alredy install Pillow using `pip install Pillow` but Pycharm doesn't recognize it. I read something about the venv but the reality is that I did not understand several things jajaja.

UPDATE

[image: Maybe this is the problem, apparently I have 2 python versions installed]

Maybe this is the problem, apparently I have 2 python versions installed

Comment: error shows it needs library `zlib` (created in C/C++). Use Google "zlib Windows" to find it.

Comment: Didn't work, It keep sending the same error. I installed zlib version 1.2.3 from here http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zlib.htm

Comment: it may need also `zlib-dev` with C/C++ headers (files .h) - it may need them to compile some C/C++ code.

Comment: you may have two Pythons installed and you installed it in one Python (using `pip`) but PyCharm use other Python. In PyCharm in settings you can select different Python - with installed `pillow` - and maybe it will work.

Comment: See the update in the question pls

Comment: image shows only one Python but if you know location of other Python then there is button `...` and you can search and select other Python.

Comment: maybe use `"system interpreter"` instead of `virtual environment` and you will not have to install it if you have it installed in `system interpreter`

Comment: Thanks man!, it worked. I changed to the system interpreter. But there is no problem of using it instead of a ```virtual enviroment```?

Comment: if you don't need two different versions of Pillow then it is no problem. Frankly, I'm to lazy to create virtual environment for every code which I write to answers on Stackoverflow and I always use system interpreter. You can use again virtual environment when you resolve problem with pillow but now you can use system interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading your pip version

```
python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
```

[Source](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4242)